# Как получить текст с строки в python

Tags: python, парсер

*Есть текст:*

```
Вадим 22 годика. Полицейский в 32 отделении
```

*Как можно получить текст 'Полицейский в 32 отделении' от точки с пробелом?*

Comment: `res = re.sub(r"^[^.]*?\.", "", text)`

Comment: Пробел захватился с необходимым текстом

Comment: Как должен работать скрипт если в тексте будет несколько предложений (точек)?

Comment: В получаемом мною тексте при парсинге html страницы, текст не содержит двух и более точек, только одна

Comment: Дело в том, что мне необходимо получить все символы после точки с пробелом, будьте внимательны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Можно так сделать и ошибок не будет:*

```
text = 'Вадим 22 годика. Полицейский в 32 отделении'

dot = text.index('.') +2
end = len(text)

print(text[dot: end])
```

*Результат:*

```
Полицейский в 32 отделении
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text = 'Вадим 22 годика. Полицейский в 32 отделении'
text.split('. ')[1]
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Угнал)

Comment: В некоторых случаях не работает и просто отправляет 2 символ.

Comment: Значит некоторые строки состоят из одного предложения и разделитель по точке с пробелом не работает.